# About the inclusion of a license in a post

Tags: discussion

I am in the habit of often specifying the license on what I write, for
many reasons.  This license is usually The Creative Commons license CC
BY-SA. It does not create any conflict with StackExchange because that
is precisely the license that is needed for StackExchange as specified
in the [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal). So the operation of StackExchange can in no way be disrupted by such a
license on a post.

There is nothing in the Terms of Service, or anywhere that I could
see, that prohibits this.

I can understand that having a license on each little bit of
information can be bothersome for users of the site, and is not very
meaningful anyway. Hence I am refraining from using it on smaller
pieces of writing. On a larger piece, it is small enough that it is
hardly noticeable.

**Why do I want to do it ?**

The first reason is that a lot of people will copy a document without
thinking further about copyright issues.  They will usually keep the
license if it is there, but will not bother when it is implicit. Given
that I am using a pseudo, that quickly makes an orphan work with no
license on the web, which some people could appropriate through
specific legislations, and I do not want that. I have no certainty
that anyone, other than myself or close relatives, will want and have
the right in the future to preserve open access to what I write.

The second reason is educational. It is important in the digital world
that people understand the existence of licenses, and their role. It
is apparent to me that users of StackExchange do not. Licenses may
protect the rights and income of authors in some cases, but they may
also protect works and the right of all people to access and use them.
That form of awareness is socially extremely important, and scientists
should more than all others be aware of it as it is crucial for their
work.

Should I remind the users of this community that the [open access
movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Declaration_on_Open_Access_to_Knowledge_in_the_Sciences_and_Humanities) is nowadays championned by the academic world in general, and
is [supported by the best universities and research centers](http://oa.mpg.de/lang/en-uk/berlin-prozess/signatoren/) in the
world (including several I worked for). In addition, its origins are
to be traced to the physics community and the work of physicist Paul
Ginsparg who created [arXiv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArXiv), the first open archive, at the Los Alamos
National Laboratory.

This historical role of the physics community makes it all the more
worrisome to find out that many of its current members do not
understand the role and effect of the appropriate use of licenses.

The last reason is simply to say thank you to people like Lawrence Lessig
and the whole Creative Commons community, and indirectly to Richard
M. Stallman who invented the type of licenses now used in
StackExchange and many other places to preserve everyone's access to
knowledge, éducation and culture.

It is customary, and even required, in the academic community to give
references to the works we have been using. We do use these licenses
all the time, and our work owes them more and more. It seems only
fitting to mention them regularly, without abusing it on minor
contributions.

**Why am I saying this ?**

My remarks about the fact that many members of this community do not
understand the meaning and role of licenses is based on the exchange of comments
when I did include a license with one or two of my posts (I do spend
significant time on some). One user went so far as to edit my post to
remove the license, arguing that it was controversial.

Being controversial does not seem to me a sufficient reason to erase
something. Controversy is an essential ingredient of creation and
advancement of knowledge. Free speech was actually an academic
creation, and some universities still maintain an age-old tradition of
having (now symbolic) bodyguards for people defending their doctoral
dissertation, so that they can speak freely. Free speech is supposed
to be the rule, unless a clear problem can be identified, to say
things as loosely as possible. This was just this user's opinion
against mine, and though he may be a trusted user, that is obviously
not his kind of expertise.

As a matter of fact, erasing a license or any kind of copyright
information from a work is generally an offense punishable by
law, probably in his country, certainly in mine, in the USA and in
most countries in the world. I do not mean this as any kind of threat,
but only as an example of general illiteracy in those matters, which
actually justifies my position above, especially in regard to
education. Actually he would have a good defense, the only possible
one: this is the license demanded on this site, so that he was not
really changing anything. But if that is the case, why erase it ? It
obviously is not controversial.

Comment: Of course, whatever consensus/ideas/recommendations are reached here are applicable to the entire network, so it may be worth bringing this up on [metase] where there is a broader user base (and more SE personnel attention).

Comment: @ChrisWhite It occurred to me that most users on this site are
scientists, and furthermore physicists. I do not write only to achieve
a result, but I also value comments and opinions. Hence I considered
that raising the issue here was the right place, and I still do for
the moment.

Comment: I disagree (-1). It makes it seem (Even if it is not supposed to) as if you don't want anyone to help spread whatever you have written. P.S. I am the user who removed the license from your post. It is ***not*** punishable by law (in any country) because your answers and questions can be edited. Something like what wikipedia says "If you do not wish your contributions to be copied and redistributed at will, please do not post it here." : )

Comment: @dimension10 - Unrelated replies - 
Many things are not what they seem to be. - I knew
you did the erasing, but that was not relevant for the
discussion. - Hopefully we all do what we think is right, though most
likely some of us are wrong. - I know about Wikipedia and I am a
contributor. - BTW thank you for the KK comment.

Answer (score 7):

It's not that we don't understand the need for licenses.

However, there are two issues with having an explicit CC-BY-SA license on the post:

- It's completely unnecessary. The footer mentions CC-BY-SA 3.0. The people who actually follow licenses will look for it there. The people who ignore them, well, they would ignore it anyway  wherever you keep the license (of course you can put up a takedown request or ask SE to do so if you find improperly attributed material).
- It's misleading. It gives the impression that users are allowed to specify any license they want -- this is false, all of the content *must* be CC-BY-SA

> As a matter of fact, erasing a license or any kind of copyright information from a work is generally an offense punishable by law, probably in his country, certainly in mine, in the USA and in most countries in the world.

Except that the license wasn't erased. The license was already there, in the footer.

> My remarks about the fact that many members of this community do not understand the meaning and role of licenses is based on the exchange of comments when I did include a license with one or two of my posts (I do spend significant time on some)

I assume you are basing your "fact" on [this comment exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/69245/7433): I (and most pobably the others) do indeed understand how licensing works, and have been using CC-BY-SA for a while now. We also know that SE *already* licenses all material as CC-BY-SA (3.0), so there was no need for the license blurb (and as mentioned above, it can be harmful too)

Comment: The other misleading part is that it *suggests* that the author of the post is the point of contact for licensing issues, which is just plain false. Stackexchange must attribute the authors, but the content is *licensed by* Stackexchange itself. If you submit a paper to a journal, even an open-access journal, you would not be in a position to say "I hereby grant others the right to use this work as follows..." or anything of the sort since you are not licensing the material to the readers. Your role in licensing ends when you turn over rights to Stackexchange.

Comment: @ChrisWhite That sort of is point #2, however feel free to edit that in if you wish :) (Just about to reboot my laptop, may not be able to come online till I fix a few things)

Comment: @ChrisWhite you don't turn your rights over to Stack Exchange. SE posts are the copyright *of the author* and are licensed *by* the author *to* Stack Exchange under the terms of the CC-BY-SA license.

Comment: (that doesn't change anything else in this thread though - it was just a technical clarification)

Answer (score 5):

As [Manishearth notes](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4514/520), the [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal) are quite clear on how material on the site is licensed. If you don't want the material licensed that way then don't post it to the site.

As the copyright holder, you are obviously free to offer the material under another license if you want (the Creative Commons licenses being non-exclusive), but you don't get to do that on Stack Exchange's dime (by posting that offer on their websites); instead you should make that second offer in another venue.

Answer (score 4):

Another reason for not adding your own license to post here is that it gives the impression that other posts are not similarly licensed, and that authors here get to pick their license terms.  Neither of those are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I wish that physics.SE users would give as much thought to the copyright of third-party content as they do to this discussion. When I flagged the embedding of a photograph protected by copyright into a post, my flag was classified as "helpful" yet the image remains.

Perhaps there should be regular reminders that only content from Wikimedia Commons (or equivalent websites if they exist) may be freely embedded into posts. For all other content protected by copyright, the right way to go about this is to put a link to the web page on which it resides. It's an inconvenience because readers then have to click on the link to view the content, but it's the only way to be sure that one does not run afoul of copyright.

"Fair Use" is probably O.K. for quoting brief excerpts of a text, but I doubt it is O.K. as a justification for embedding a photograph or illustration.

Comment: Thumbnails pix are fair use in the USA, but not in some European countries. Embedded links are not ok. Links to the pix itself are diputed by some.  Links to be clicked to reach a page where the pix is, not the pix itself, is ok.

Comment: That flag should have been declined, since moderators are not authorized to handle copyright violations. If you find something you believe to be a copyright violation, you would need to ask the copyright holder to file a DMCA request following the procedure described in the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal).

Comment: @babou _links_ are always okay, embedded _images_ may or may not be.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Afaik, an embedded link, making the image look as if it came from the same site as the rest of the page, is a violation in Europe, and I would be surprised if it were not in America. If you have to click, that is considered a reference. But you may still get angry messages if you click directly the image rather than the page containing it.

Comment: @babou A link does not make the image look as if it came from the same site as the rest of the page. [This is a link](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4512/about-the-inclusion-of-a-license-in-a-post/4519?noredirect=1#comment11978_4519). It is something you have to click on (so, perhaps the same thing you're calling a "reference"). Anyway, whatever you call it, it's always legal.

Comment: @David I would feel very uncomfortable "ratting out" a fellow user (who probably did not intend any harm) by alerting the copyright holder, would have preferred for this to be handled "behind the scenes".

Comment: @Eugene Noted, but the DMCA process is legally the only method by which a copyright violation can be handled here on SE. If you don't want the copyright holder to be aware of the possible infringement, your only option is to do nothing. Keep in mind that the way it usually works is that the copyright holder files a DMCA notice, the content is removed from the site, and that's the end of it. No further consequences for the OP.

Comment: @Eugene Could I email you for some question about German copyright ?  My email is babou@inbox.com

Comment: Dear @babou I am sorry if I gave you the impression of being an expert on copyright law, in Germany or anywhere. I am not. You may want to try the Reference Desk on Wikipedia :)